# Reading constants values from python file and using it in a shell

Tags: python

PatchConstants.py:

```
class PatchConstants:

 PATCHHOME='/scratch/app/product/fmw/obpinstall/patching'
 FMWHOME='/scratch/app/product/fmw'
 DOMAINPATH=FMWHOME+'/user_projects/domains/'
 def __init__(self):
    pass
```

b.sh:

```
from PatchConstants import PatchConstants
path = PatchConstants.PATCHHOME
```

I want to extract python constant variable in a shell scripts.

Is it possible?

Comment: How reliable does this have to be? What can we use? Can we run Python (e.g. `import b; print(b.path)`)? Is grepping PatchConstants acceptable?

Comment: I just want the constant variable value of PatchConstant.py in a shell variable

Comment: It is still unclear to me. Do you want to analyze your script from an outside shell or do you want to set the variables so that you can call shell scripts from your python code (e.g. via `os.putenv`)?

Comment: You should probably be going the other way with this. Define your variables in a shell script and create a wrapper for your Python script that sources the constants and then calls your python. Within Python you can grab the values using os.environ['PATCHHOME']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the `-c` option of python to run python commands and deliver the result to the shell variable.

Just like:

`path = $(python -c "from PatchConstants import PatchConstant ; print PatchConstants.PATCHHOME")`